# Prove that the angle is 90°

Tags: geometry

$ABC$ is a triangle with $AB < AC$. 
The tangent to the circumcircle at $A$ meets line $BC$ at $P$. Points $E$ and $F$ are the feet of the altitudes from $B$ and $C$ respectively. A line from $A$ parallel to $BC$ meets line $EF$ at $Q$. $M$ is the midpoint of $BC$. Prove that $PQ$ and $AM$ are perpendicular.

(I found that $AEFH$ and $BEFC$ are cyclic with diameters $AH$ and $BC$ respectively. Also $AQ$ is tangent to circumcircle of $AEFH$ and $QEF || AP$.  Also line $PBC$ is radical axis of the circumcircles of $ABC$ and $BEFC$. Line $QEF$ is radical axis of circumcircles of $AEFH$ and $BEFC$.
I think that the synthetic solution will come from radical axes and radical centers but I can't seem to proceed.
Also I would like to know some other solutions like trig, coordinates, inversion etc.)

Comment: Provide a drawing if you want help with this one...

Comment: I tried to upload the diagram but i was unable to as I am new to this site and do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will give a proof for the problem in the OP by also adding some bonus properties. The given geometric constellation can be embedded in the following one, isolated in a new statement below that uses the same notation from the OP for a simple parallel (against my will). The bonus properties come according to my principle that if two lines are perpendicular, and if the point "has a meaning", then a faithful proof should elucidate, or at least mention this. Full details are given, this makes the exposition longer. For a short exposition stop after the statement. (Which is longer than the proof, and fill in the details by a glance.)

---

> **Given:**
>
> - Let $\Delta ABC$ be a triangle with $AB<AC$. We denote by $H$, $O$ its orthocenter, respectively its circumcenter.
> - The tangent in $A$ to the circumcircle $(O)=(ABC)$ intersects $BC$ in $P$, so $OA\perp AP$.
> - Let $D,E,F$ be the feet of the altitudes in $\Delta ABC$ constructed from $A,B,C$, respectively. Let $M$ be the mid point of $BC$.
> - We construct the Euler nine-points circle $(DEFM)=(9)$, centered in $9$, and would like also to single out some following further points on it. Let $X$ be the second point of intersection of $AM$ with $(9)$, here $X\ne M$. Let $Y\in(9)$ be the mid point of $AH$.
> - Let $Q$ be the intersection of the parallel through $A$ to $BC$.
> - Let $Z$ be the intersection of $EF$ with $BC$.
> - Let $T$ be the intersection of $MY$ with $AP$.
> - Let $\Xi$ be the intersection of $MH$ and $AZ$.
>
> ---
>
> [image: Geometry problem related to the Euler nine points circle, stackexchange 3496882, dan_fulea]
>
> ---
>
> **Then:**
>
> - (1) The lines $EF\| AP$ have a direction perpendicular to $AO\| M9YT$.
> - (2) $Y$ is the orthocenter of $\Delta APM$ and $P,Y,X$ are colinear.
> - (3) $H$ is the orthocenter of $\Delta AZM$, so in particular $ZH\|AYM$, both being perpendicular on $AXM$.
> - (4) The triangles $\Delta YPD$ and $\Delta YQA$ are similar, in particular $P,Y(,X),Q$ are colinear, and their common line is perpendicular on $AM$ in $X$.

---

**Proof:**

(1) In the Euler circle we have $EF\perp MY$, since $MF=MB=MC=ME$ and $YF=YH=YA=YE$ (in a right triangle the median from the right angle is half hypotenuse), so $\Delta EMY=\Delta FMY$ so the chord $EF$ is perpendicular on the diameter $MY$ in $(9)$.

Then we have $EF\|AP$, since $EF$ is an "anti-parallel" to $BC$, using (blue) angles explicitly, $\widehat{PAB}=\frac 12\overset\frown{AB}=\hat C=\widehat{EFA}$.

And of course $PA\perp AO$ by construction.

(2) This is again simple. By (1) we have $MY\perp AP$, and of course $PBDMC$. So $Y$ is orthocenter in $\Delta APM$. The third height $AY$ intersects the side $AM$ in a point $X'$ such thet $\widehat YXM= 90^\circ$, so $X'=X$, since $YM$ is diameter in $(9)$.

(3) To be able to focus only on the few points involved, here is an other picture:

[image: Geometry problem related to the Euler nine points circle, stackexchange 3496882, part of the whole picture, dan_fulea]

To have a simple proof, we reverse slightly the order of the construction of the points, with reference to the above picture. We construct first the points $A,B,C;D,E,F;H$ as above. Then we draw the circle $(AEFH)$ with diameter $AH$, and denote by $\Xi,\Upsilon$ the intersections of this circle with the lines $ZA$, $ZH$, respectively. Let $A\Upsilon$ intersect the line $PZBC$ in a point $M'$. (We want $M'=M$, so let us show it.) The using the power of the point $Z$ w.r.t. different circles, we have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
ZD\cdot ZM'
&=ZH\cdot Z\Upsilon &&\text{ powers of $Z$ w.r.t. the circle }(M'DHY)\\
&=ZE\cdot ZF &&\text{ powers of $Z$ w.r.t. the circle }(AFHE)\\
&=ZD\cdot ZM &&\text{ powers of $Z$ w.r.t. the circle }(9)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
In a computer game, $M$ would inherit the property of $M'$, so $AH\Upsilon\perp AM$. Given that $AHD\perp AM$, the point $H$ is the orthocenter in $\Delta AZM$, and thus the third height $MH$ goes through the projection of $H$ on $AZ$, which is $\Xi$.

(4) We first observe that $APZQ$ is a parallelogram, $AQ\| PZ$ by construction, and $EF\|AP$. (Or use angle chasing to show that (two of) the "red angles" in $P,Q,Z$ have the measure $\hat B-\hat C$.)

The two triangles questioned about similarity have each a right angle in $A,D$, so it is enought to show a proportionality of two pairs of sides. We take the easy ones, and want to show (!):
$$
\begin{aligned} 
\frac{AQ}{PD}
&\ \overset{(!)}= \ 
\frac{AY}{YD}\ . &&\text{ Equivalently:}
\\
\frac{PZ}{PD}
&\ \overset{(!)}= \
\frac{AY}{YD}\ . &&\text{ Equivalently, using derived proportions:}
\\
\frac{PZ}{PD-PZ}
&\ \overset{(!)}= \
\frac{AY}{YD-AY}\ . &&\text{ Equivalently:}
\\
\frac{PZ}{ZD}
&\ \overset{(!)}= \
\frac{YH}{HD}\ . &&\text{ True, because of }ZH\|PY\ .
\end{aligned} 
$$
(Since $ZH$, $PY$ are perpendicular on $AM$ in $\Upsilon$, respectively $X$.)

The two angles in $Y$ of the two similar triangles are equal, given that $A,Y,D$ are colinear, we obtain $Q,Y,P$ colinear. And we already know $X$ is on the same line (with $P,Y$). The final touch is
$$ 
AXM\perp AYXQ\text{ in }X\ .
$$

$\square$

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Hint: Use the fact that in every triangle the radius OA is perpendicular to EF. It is also perpendicular to tangent line PA. Now you have to show that $\angle MAO=\angle PQF$ through angle chasing. Hence other rays will also be perpendicular, i.e MN is perpendicular to PQ.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Your welcome, if the hint was useful and you found a solution using it, please share it with others. Also do not forget voting!

Comment: I only have one question - how do you get that EF is perpendicular to the radius?

Comment: This can be another question. You can post it, I am sure you will get good answers.

Comment: Lota1234, I asked this as a question in this site.See geometry problems.

Comment: Sirous thanks a lot. I now understand why these two are perpendicular.

Comment: @sirous Please give full proofs, hints are ok when the remaining part is straightforward, this is not the case in this case. Please mention in advance when starting an answer if a full proof or not is given. (Since some potential "answerers" like me sometimes skip read questions with answers, if some lines in the answer seem to lead to quickly to a solution. In this case i took a closer look by chance.) And finally: If asked why $EF\perp AO$, *used* in the hint, it would be fair to give the argument.

Comment: dan_fulea, I asked the last point. I will be pleased to see an answer because I worked on it for some times and got no result. Would you try on it? My hint can be an option.